# Wowza server-side Stream.play() by frame

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

You can add a media source to the `Stream`'s current playlist and play it in its entirety using:

```
stream1.play("mp4:sample.mp4", 0, -1, true);
```

And you can use the offset and duration to start 5 seconds into a clip and play 7 seconds of that clip like this:

```
stream1.play("mp4:sample.mp4", 5, 7, true);
```

But is there a way to control the playback by frames instead of seconds? Start at frame 320 and play for a duration of 210 frames. Is there any way to achieve this level of granularity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [documentation](http://www.wowza.com/resources/WowzaStreamingEngine_ServerSideAPI.pdf) for the `Stream` class doesn't mention a way to set the `start` and `length` arguments of the `play` function using frames.

However, you can change the resolution from seconds to milliseconds using `Stream.setTimesInMilliseconds(true)`:

> public void **setTimesInMilliseconds**(boolean timesInMilliseconds)
>
> If true start time and duration and are milliseconds. If false startTime
>   and duration are in seconds.

You can calculate the start and length based the frame rate and frame offsets.

I recommend you also ask on the Wowza [forum](http://www.wowza.com/forums/forum.php), since not all new features are properly documented.